# Very confused by cors with fetch and when an options request is made

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, cors, fetch

I have the following code that uses [whatwg fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch):

```
  const headers = new Headers();

  //uncommenting this causes the preflight options request to be sent 
  //headers.append('x-something', 'foo');

  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/managers', {
    headers,
    credentials: 'include'
  });
```

The above code does not make a preflight options request unless I uncomment this line:

```
 //headers.append('x-something', 'foo');
```

I have the server configured like this to allow the localhost request:

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:4040'
}));
```

If I make the request with the `credentials: 'include'` option, I get the following error in the chrome browser:

> Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:5000/api/managers. Credentials
>   flag is 'true', but the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header is
>   ''. It must be 'true' to allow credentials. Origin
>   'http://localhost:4040' is therefore not allowed access.

If I remove `credentials: 'include'` but have the custom header like this:

```
  headers.append('x-something', 'foo');

  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/managers', {
    headers
  });
```

Then the chrome network tab just shows an OPTIONS request with a `204 No Content` response even though a JSON response is returned from the server.

I don't understand why the chrome network tab is not showing a GET request with the JSON response as it is happening.

The request and response looks like this with a 204 no content response:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:5000/api/managers
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:204 No Content
Remote Address:[::1]:5000
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:x-something
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,HEAD,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:4040
Connection:keep-alive
Date:Wed, 02 Nov 2016 21:23:24 GMT
Vary:Accept-Encoding
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:x-something
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:5000
Origin:http://localhost:4040
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:4040/base/winratio
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36
Name
managers
/api
info?t=1478121804370
/sockjs-node
```

IF I make the code simply this:

```
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/managers', {
  });
```

Then the google chrome network tab just shows a GET request with a 200 HTTP response and the json it is returning:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:5000/api/managers
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:5000
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:4040
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1104
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 02 Nov 2016 21:35:21 GMT
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control:off
X-Download-Options:noopen
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:5000
Origin:http://localhost:4040
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:4040/base/winratio
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36
Name
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests

Answer (score 1):

As the error message indicate, your server needs to have `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` as response header. This is also explained in Fetch: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-and-credentials

Answer (score 1):

"Some requests don’t trigger a CORS preflight. Those are called “simple requests” in this article, though the Fetch spec (which defines CORS) doesn’t use that term."

Continue reading in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests